# Sqlite Database cannot be access from different JVM

Tags: java

I have created a Sqlite database and  insert data in the table it have .

From two different eclipse i am able to fetch the table data content .

But sqlite database did not allow to access by more than one jvm .

But i am using two different Eclipse Please guide me how to proceed

Comment: You should provide more information. Post your database related code and mark the location where the error appears. What JDBC driver do you use? What error do you get?  Please post the full stack trace. And describe the test setting. Are you trying to run two instances of the same program accessing the same database? Or different programs? Without that information it is very hard to help you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sqlite database can access from different JVM or not](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41034053/sqlite-database-can-access-from-different-jvm-or-not)

Answer (score 0):

I am using sqlite-jdbc-3.8.11.2.jar

public class TestThread2 {

```
private String threadName;

public static void main(final String args[]) {
    final PrintDemo1 PD = new PrintDemo1();
    final PrintDemo26 PD6 = new PrintDemo26();

    final ThreadDemo1 T1 = new ThreadDemo1("Thread - 1 ", PD);
    final ThreadDemo1 T2 = new ThreadDemo1("Thread - 2 ", PD);
    final ThreadDemo1 T3 = new ThreadDemo1("Thread - 3 ", PD);
    final ThreadDemo1 T4 = new ThreadDemo1("Thread - 4 ", PD);
    final ThreadDemo1 T5 = new ThreadDemo1("Thread - 5 ", PD);

    final ThreadDemo26 T6 = new ThreadDemo26("Thread - 26 ", PD6);
    final ThreadDemo26 T7 = new ThreadDemo26("Thread - 27 ", PD6);
    final ThreadDemo26 T8 = new ThreadDemo26("Thread - 28 ", PD6);
    final ThreadDemo26 T9 = new ThreadDemo26("Thread - 29 ", PD6);
    final ThreadDemo26 T10 = new ThreadDemo26("Thread - 30 ", PD6);

    T6.start(); // write
    T1.start(); // read

    T7.start(); // write
    T2.start();// read

    T8.start(); // write
    T3.start(); // read

    T9.start(); // write
    T4.start(); // read
    T10.start(); // write
    T5.start(); // read

    T3.start();
    T4.start();
    T5.start();

    // wait for threads to end
    try {

        T6.join();

        T1.join();

        T7.join();
        T2.join();

        T8.join();
        T3.join();

        T9.join();
        T4.join();
        T10.join();
        T5.join();
    } catch (final Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Interrupted");
    }
}
```